# Obtaining rated current from 5 volt rail of pc PSU

Tags: power-supply

I need to supply a minimum of 0.5 amps to each port of a number of 10 port USB 2.0 hubs.  I have succeeded using 8 amp wall warts so I'm reasonable sure the hubs are capable.  I'm powering 8 hubs  so that's more wall warts than I want to deal with.  I modified a PC PSU, adding a load resistor (10 ohn 10 watt), power led and on/off switch following the many on-line guides.

I have 6 cables off the 5 volt bar, everything is solder and shrink wrap, psu starts as it should.  It does supply power to the USB hubs but only a limited amount.  I estimate it's about 2.5-3 amps, as all ten of the devices do not work correctly.  The measured voltage at each line is 5.01 volts.

I have modified 2 PSU's, one rated at 400 watts with 28 amps for the 3.3 and 5 volt rail combined.  The second PSU is rated at 40 amps for the 3.3/5volt rail combined.

I think the problem is because these are "regulated" power supplies, but I'm a noob and I'm totally lost at understanding why I'm not getting even close to the rated current of the PSU's.  I would appreciate any advise or constructive criticism.

Comment: how much current does each hub need? If you've got 5v on each hub then the problem is not the power supply.

Comment: I need 5 amps to each hub, 10 devises per hub each requiring 0.5 amps.  The modified psu well power 5 of the devises (ASIC's).  I can power several hubs with the pc psu and each well have 4-5 of the devices power up, that's half of the number in the hub.  When the hubs are powered by the wall warts all devices power up.  When I use a wall wart with a 5 or more amp rating all 10 ASIC's power up.  With a 3 amp wall wart, 6 devices power up, and so on depending on the amp rating of the wall wart being used.

Comment: The pc psu behaves like it is a 2.5 amp power supply, i get this from each of the attached connectors (6).  I'm getting the same results from two different psu's, a 28 amp and a 40 amp.  I have talked to others doing this same project and they have had the same results, only 2-3 amps per connection from the psu.

Comment: Do you have a load resistor on the 12v AND 5v rails, or just the 5v rail? Also, have you used an actual ammeter to measure the current, or are you just guestimating?

Comment: I did the 10 ohm, 10 watt load resister to the 5 volt rail only.  Nothing is connected to the 12 volt or the 3.3 volt rails.  Do I need to add a load resister to the 12V rail?  Yes, just a guesstament on the amps, seeing how other power supplies have preformed.

Comment: @user182165 try adding a load to the 12v rail. Some supplies are finicky.